# Insert a "tag x" in variations chart if without stock

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to insert a (x) inside variations without stock (quantity="0")
i'm working inside a ecommerce plataform that not have support for this.

my codes JS: (helped by the forum)

```
    /*var buttons = "";
$("select option").each(function () {
buttons += "<input type='button' value='" + this.value + "'/>";    
});

$("select").replaceWith(buttons);
*/

var selectName = $('select').attr('name');

// add a hidden element with the same name as the select
var hidden = $('<input type="hidden" name="'+selectName+'">');
hidden.val($('select').val());
hidden.insertAfter($('select'));

$("select option").unwrap().each(function() {
var btn = $('<div class="btn">'+$(this).text()+'</div>');
if($(this).is(':checked')) btn.addClass('on');
$(this).replaceWith(btn);
});
```

HTML + CSS EMBED:

```
<!-- Variações -->
<iluria.if.product.has.variations>
<div class="product-variations-container">
$iluria.product.variations
</div>                              
<script src="variations.js"></script>
<style>
*.product-variations-container > div:nth-child(4) { display: none; }*
div.btn {display: inline-block;border: 2px solid #ccc;margin-right: 5px;padding: 2px 5px;cursor: pointer;}
div.btn.on {background-color: #777;color: white;}
</style>
</iluria.if.product.has.variations>

    $(document).on('click', '.btn', function() {
    $('.btn').removeClass('on');
    $(this).addClass('on');
    $('input[name="'+selectName+'"]').val($(this).text());
    });
```

*Forum suggest to insert this*

[Screen that i want:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCKT9.jpg)

Link of one product "P" + "M" have stock, "G" not

Link product: http://www.hdmclothing.com.br/pd-3d1b01-sainha-azul.html

Thanks!